# Alternative `batch` command for resources rather than load

Tags: command-line, unix, batch, at

I like the `at` and `batch` commands for scheduling long running tasks I do not plan to stick around to see. But my longest running tasks share resources other than just the CPU (databases, free disk space, and resident memory are all an issue).

I want to specify what resources a task would need and then have them run whenever all their resources become available. It sounds like this must already exist, but what command does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a [`cron`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html) task which is scheduled "frequently" (whether once a minute or hour depends on what you need).  In the task, you could then make those checks, and go ahead and run it when the conditions are met.

If this is a one-time task, your task could (since it runs with your permissions) update the [crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) to remove itself.